# interfacing circuit for EEG signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, biopotential

I was looking to an interfacing circuit for EEG signal , and i get this schematic , which is shown below , my question is , what is the point `pov` , it's said to be used for `common mode impedance` , so what is that mean ?[image]

Comment: Maybe you can show us where the diagram came from?

Comment: @Andyaka from this paper [link](http://www.biosemi.com/publications/artikel4.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit is an [instrumentation amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier) with the normal Rg split into two. The center point will have a potential equal to the average of the two input electrodes.

That voltage can be buffered and fed to a third electrode to establish a common-mode voltage range at the patient with respect to the circuit ground. Ideally, the common-mode voltage will be close to zero, so that imperfections in the instrumentation amplifier (Common Mode Rejection Ratio = CMRR) won't interfere with the signal- also if the common mode voltage gets too far from ground, the amplifier will no longer work properly at all- one or more of the amplifiers will go outside its input or output range.

**Edit**: Based on your paper link, it appears that the average potential (Pav) point is driven by a buffered electrode voltage rather than being used to drive the voltage on the ground wrt the patient. The overall effect is similar, the common-mode voltage is driven to close to zero since the impedance looking into Pav is Rg/2, which is typically very low.

The relevant quote is:

> The "average" of the inputs voltages (= common mode voltage) is obtained by an extra CM-sense electrode and an extra input section. A low-impedance version of the CM-sense input signal is used to drive the coupling point Pav

The overall acceptable operating area for a 3-amplifier in-amp looks something like this (from a [Maxim site](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4034)). The shape is correct, but Vref should be Vcc/2 not Vcc*2 in the second diagram. The shape of the lower diagram is correct, but it should say Vcc/2 for Vref which is when the input is near ground in your circuit.

[image]

Comment: thanks , but what you mean by `the common mode voltage gets too far from ground` ?

Comment: The inputs both must not be too far from the circuit ground. The amplifier delivers a multiple of the differences in input voltages (so they must be fairly close to each other in voltage) but the average input also can't be too far from common("ground").

Answer (score 2):

That configuration is an instrumentation amplifier.  The point you ask about is where you can tap to get the common mode voltage, which can be fed back to the body in what would be called "driven leg" if this were an ECG amplifier.  It effectively reduces electrode impedance for common mode signals, reducing noise.

Comment: So , I can measure this signal then subtract it from the output of the diffrential amplifire , so the commom mode voltage be canceled ?